# Using SQL to determine cidr value of a subnet mask

Tags: sql, subnet, bitmask, cidr

I'd like to find a way to do a SQL query that will calculate the cidr (bit representation) of a subnet mask stored in the database.  So for example, I've got either 255.255.255.0 or its decimal value (4294967040) stored in the database.  I'd like to do a select and get back /24 representation via the query.

I've done things like the following to determine the last IP of a subnet so I'm hoping to do something similar to determine the cidr representation of a mask.

```
select concat(inet_ntoa(ip_addr),'-',
    inet_ntoa(ip_addr+(POWER(2,32)-ip_mask-1))) range 
from subnets 
order by ip_addr
```

Preferably this would be a SQL statement that would work under mysql, postgres, oracle etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think I have found the solution to my issue.  Here is what I have done:

```
select CONCAT(INET_NTOA(ip_addr),'/',32-log2((4294967296-ip_mask))) net 
from subnets 
order by ip_addr
```

Basically I take my decmial mask and subtract it from the maximum decimal value.  I then to a log2 on that value to get the logarithm value.  Then simply subtract that from 32 (the maximum bit available).

Hope that helps others.

Thanks

Comment: I checked this against all the values in this table and found it to be accurate: https://kthx.at/subnetmask/.

Answer (score 3):

SQL queries don't have a procedural looping construct (notwithstanding procedural language), but you can compare one set of rows to another set of rows, which is kind of like a loop.

You only have 32 possible subnet masks.  In cases like this, it makes sense to create a small table that stores these 32 masks and the associated CIDR number.

```
CREATE TABLE cidr (
  bits INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY,
  mask INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO cidr (bits) VALUES
  ( 1), ( 2), ( 3), ( 4), ( 5), ( 6), ( 7), ( 8), ( 9), (10),
  (11), (12), (13), (14), (15), (16), (17), (18), (19), (20),
  (21), (22), (23), (24), (25), (26), (27), (28), (29), (30),
  (31), (32);

UPDATE cidr SET mask = ((POWER(2,32)-1)<<(32-bits)) & (POWER(2,32)-1);

SELECT CONCAT(s.ip_addr, '/', c.bits)
FROM cidr c JOIN subnets s ON (c.mask = inet_aton(s.ip_mask));
```

Comment: Adding a table was what I had hoped to avoid.  I was hoping there were further mathematical calculations that could be done to convert from decimal to binary then count the bits.  Thanks though, this was helpfull

Answer (score 1):

e.g. you need to convert `255.255.255.252` netmask into bit mask.

I always use this simple query (PostgreSQL) :

```
SELECT 32-length(trim(((split_part('255.255.255.252','.',1)::bigint*(256^3)::bigint +
                        split_part('255.255.255.252','.',2)::bigint*(256^2)::bigint +
                        split_part('255.255.255.252','.',3)::bigint*256 +
                        split_part('255.255.255.252','.',4)::bigint)::bit(32))::text,'1'));
```

not as nice as could be, but it's short and working like a charm..

Answer (score 0):

```
--
-- Dumping routines for database
--
/*!50003 DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `INET_ATOC` */;
/*!50003 SET @saved_cs_client      = @@character_set_client */ ;
/*!50003 SET @saved_cs_results     = @@character_set_results */ ;
/*!50003 SET @saved_col_connection = @@collation_connection */ ;
/*!50003 SET character_set_client  = utf8 */ ;
/*!50003 SET character_set_results = utf8 */ ;
/*!50003 SET collation_connection  = utf8_general_ci */ ;
/*!50003 SET @saved_sql_mode       = @@sql_mode */ ;
/*!50003 SET sql_mode              = 'ALLOW_INVALID_DATES' */ ;
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `INET_ATOC`(`paramNETMASK` varchar(15)) RETURNS int(2) unsigned
    DETERMINISTIC
    COMMENT 'Converts an IPv4 netmask in dotted decimal notation to a CIDR integer between 0 and 32'
BEGIN
    DECLARE `netmask` int unsigned;
    DECLARE `cidr` int unsigned;
    SET `netmask` = INET_ATON(`paramNETMASK`);
    IF (`netmask` IS NULL)
    THEN
        RETURN NULL;
    ELSE
        SET `cidr` = 0;
        countNetBits: WHILE (`cidr` < 32)
        DO
            IF ( (0x80000000 & `netmask`) = 0x80000000 )
            THEN
                SET `netmask` = 0xFFFFFFFF & (`netmask` << 1);
                SET `cidr` = `cidr` + 1;
            ELSE
                LEAVE countNetBits;
            END IF;
        END WHILE;
        IF (`netmask` != 0)
        THEN
            RETURN NULL;
        END IF;
        RETURN `cidr`;
    END IF;
END ;;
DELIMITER ;
/*!50003 SET sql_mode              = @saved_sql_mode */ ;
/*!50003 SET character_set_client  = @saved_cs_client */ ;
/*!50003 SET character_set_results = @saved_cs_results */ ;
/*!50003 SET collation_connection  = @saved_col_connection */ ;
/*!50003 DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `INET_CTOA` */;
/*!50003 SET @saved_cs_client      = @@character_set_client */ ;
/*!50003 SET @saved_cs_results     = @@character_set_results */ ;
/*!50003 SET @saved_col_connection = @@collation_connection */ ;
/*!50003 SET character_set_client  = utf8 */ ;
/*!50003 SET character_set_results = utf8 */ ;
/*!50003 SET collation_connection  = utf8_general_ci */ ;
/*!50003 SET @saved_sql_mode       = @@sql_mode */ ;
/*!50003 SET sql_mode              = 'ALLOW_INVALID_DATES' */ ;
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `INET_CTOA`(`paramCIDR` int) RETURNS varchar(15) CHARSET utf8
    DETERMINISTIC
    COMMENT 'Converts a CIDR suffix (integer between 0 and 32) to an IPv4 netmask in dotted decimal notation'
BEGIN
    DECLARE `netmask` int unsigned;
    IF  ( (`paramCIDR` < 0) OR (`paramCIDR` > 32) )
    THEN
        RETURN NULL;
    ELSE
        SET `netmask` = 0xFFFFFFFF - (pow( 2, (32-`paramCIDR`) ) - 1);
        RETURN INET_NTOA(`netmask`);
    END IF;
END ;;
DELIMITER ;
/*!50003 SET sql_mode              = @saved_sql_mode */ ;
/*!50003 SET character_set_client  = @saved_cs_client */ ;
/*!50003 SET character_set_results = @saved_cs_results */ ;
/*!50003 SET collation_connection  = @saved_col_connection */ ;
/*!50003 DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `getSubnet` */;
/*!50003 SET @saved_cs_client      = @@character_set_client */ ;
/*!50003 SET @saved_cs_results     = @@character_set_results */ ;
/*!50003 SET @saved_col_connection = @@collation_connection */ ;
/*!50003 SET character_set_client  = utf8 */ ;
/*!50003 SET character_set_results = utf8 */ ;
/*!50003 SET collation_connection  = utf8_general_ci */ ;
/*!50003 SET @saved_sql_mode       = @@sql_mode */ ;
/*!50003 SET sql_mode              = '' */ ;
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `getSubnet`(INOUT `paramADDR` VARCHAR(15), INOUT `paramCIDR` INT, OUT `paramMASK` VARCHAR(15), OUT `paramNETWORK` VARCHAR(15), OUT `paramBROADCAST` VARCHAR(15), OUT `paramNUMHOSTS` INT) CHARSET utf8
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE `numaddrs`  int unsigned;
    DECLARE `ipaddr`    int unsigned;
    DECLARE `netmask`   int unsigned;
    DECLARE `wildcard`  int unsigned;
    DECLARE `network`   int unsigned;
    DECLARE `broadcast` int unsigned;
    DECLARE `numhosts`  int unsigned;

    SET `ipaddr` = INET_ATON(`paramADDR`);

    IF (`ipaddr` IS NULL) OR (`paramCIDR` < 1) OR (`paramCIDR` > 30)
    THEN
        SELECT
            NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
        INTO
            `paramADDR`, `paramCIDR`, `paramMASK`, `paramNETWORK`, `paramBROADCAST`, `paramNUMHOSTS`;
    ELSE
        SET `numaddrs`  = pow( 2, (32-`paramCIDR`) );
        SET `numhosts`  = `numaddrs` - 2;
        SET `netmask`   = 0xFFFFFFFF - (`numaddrs` - 1);
        SET `wildcard`  = 0xFFFFFFFF & (~`netmask`);
        SET `network`   = `ipaddr` & `netmask`;
        SET `broadcast` = `ipaddr` | `wildcard`;

        SELECT
            INET_NTOA(`ipaddr`), `paramCIDR`, INET_NTOA(`netmask`), INET_NTOA(`network`), INET_NTOA(`broadcast`), `numhosts`
        INTO
            `paramADDR`, `paramCIDR`, `paramMASK`, `paramNETWORK`, `paramBROADCAST`, `paramNUMHOSTS`;
    END IF;
END ;;
DELIMITER ;
/*!50003 SET sql_mode              = @saved_sql_mode */ ;
/*!50003 SET character_set_client  = @saved_cs_client */ ;
/*!50003 SET character_set_results = @saved_cs_results */ ;
/*!50003 SET collation_connection  = @saved_col_connection */ ;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;
```