# Is there way to match IP with IP+CIDR straight from SELECT query?

Tags: mysql, ip, mask, bitmask, cidr

Something like

> `SELECT COUNT(*) AS c FROM BANS WHERE typeid=6 AND (SELECT ipaddr,cidr FROM BANS) MATCH AGAINST 'this_ip';`

So you don't first fetch all records from DB and then match them one-by one.

If c > 0 then were matched.

BANS table:

```
id int auto incr PK
typeid TINYINT (1=hostname, 4=ipv4, 6=ipv6)
ipaddr BINARY(128)
cidr INT
host VARCHAR(255)
```

DB: MySQL 5

IP and IPv type (4 or 6) is known when querying.

IP is for example ::1 in binary format

BANNED IP is for example ::1/64

Comment: raspi, I know this question is old, but... is your cidr column the number of one-bits in the net mask, so for ipv6 it's always 64 and for ipv4 it is a number between 0 and 32? Though I suppose 0 would ban all addresses ... :)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Remember that IPs are not a textual address, but a numeric ID. I have a similar situation (we're doing geo-ip lookups), and if you store all your IP addresses as integers (for example, my IP address is 192.115.22.33 so it is stored as 3228767777), then you can lookup IPs easily by using right shift operators.

The downside of all these types of lookups is that you can't benefit from indexes and you have to do a full table scan whenever you do a lookup. The above scheme can be improved by storing both the network IP address of the CIDR network (the beginning of the range) and the broadcast address (the end of the range), so for example to store 192.168.1.0/24 you can store two columns:

```
network     broadcast
3232235776, 3232236031
```

And then you can to match it you simply do

```
SELECT count(*) FROM bans WHERE 3232235876 >= network AND 3232235876 <= broadcast
```

This would let you store CIDR networks in the database and match them against IP addresses quickly and efficiently by taking advantage of quick numeric indexes.

*Note from discussion below*:

MySQL 5.0 includes a ranged query optimization called "[index merge intersect](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/index-merge-optimization.html#index-merge-intersection)" which allows to speed up such queries (and avoid full table scans), as long as:

- There is a multi-column index that matches exactly the columns in the query, in order. So - for the above query example, the index would need to be `(network, broadcast)`.
- All the data can be retrieved from the index. This is true for `COUNT(*)`, but is not true for `SELECT * ... LIMIT 1`.

MySQL 5.6 includes an optimization called MRR which would also speed up full row retrieval, but that is out of scope of this answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, MySQL cannot combine two indexes together. It of course will try to use the index on either network or broadcast, but as ip addresses are distibuted evenly, full table scan will be much more efficient in this case.

Comment: This myth is a bit out of date :-) starting with MySQL 5.0, the server can merge multiple indexes (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/index-merge-optimization.html). Regardless, I can't see how a full table scan is better then using an index, even if it is only 1 index.

Comment: If your filter returns more than about 10% or rows, full table scan is better. Try it :)

Comment: And you don't need COUNT(*) here, SELECT ... LIMIT 1 is enough to ban :)

Comment: And MySQL cannot combine two ranged conditions with an AND clause: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/index-merge-intersection.html

Comment: I'm really not sure where you get those ideas. (a) there is no way a full table scan is better then an index scan - granted if your index scan generates a significant number of rows that must be retrieved fully then the difference will be negligible. "Significant" here is 80%-90%, not 10!

Comment: P.S. this condition is very unlikely in this problem domain, and can be mitigated easily by only selecting on the columns in the index at which point MySQL can skip retrieving full rows and just answer from the index.

Comment: (b) You are of course right, but the original question used `count()` so I just copied that.

Comment: (c) The link you show specifically says that AND condition works. At worst it means that you have to have index(network,broadcast) to make it work efficiently. And this is only one of 3 index merge algorithms MySQL can choose to employ. Quassnoi - please read the material you link to.

Comment: Guss, believe me, I do read and check thing before I post them. If you read my link, you will see: either EQUALS condition on the whole index, or a RANGED CONDITION OVER PRIMARY KEY. You can't have two primary keys in one table, you cannot combine two RANGED (RANGED) conditions with an AND.

Comment: for (a): just checked in my database. SELECT COUNT(*) FROM it WHERE id > 10000 AND source > 0: 0,11 sec (TABLE SCAN), same with FORCE INDEX (PRIMARY): 1,58 sec, 14 times longer. PRIMARY INDEX is on ID, "id > 10000" filters out about 10% rows, "source > 0" is always TRUE.

Comment: @Quassnoi - sorry for disparaging, you are 99% correct. range scans can only be done on primary keys (with InnoDB engine, which probably means that it wont work with MyISAM engine).

Comment: That being said, if you only select on indexed columns, then even if the server scans all the rows (which it will do in the above case), it doesn't have to do a full table scan (which requires loading full rows and is very slow) - it can just load the entire index -that fits into memory most times.

Comment: ah... BTW Quassnoi: if "id>10000" filters out 10% of the rows, then you are selecting on 90% of the rows, see my point (a) above.

Comment: I just demoed this on a MySQL 5.1: with an index lookup that hits about 90% of the rows, using the index (force index) is indeed slower then a full table scan (ignore index). If the index lookup hits about 10% of the rows, (like in this question) the situation is reversed (even for range lookups).

Comment: Maybe it depends on the table data. In the tables I checked against, INDEX SCANs perform better than TABLE SCANs only if index condition covers about 10% of data or less. If table rows are long, situation may probably change.

Answer (score 4):

IPv4 addresses, network addresses and netmasks are all UINT32 numbers and are presented in human-readable form as "dotted-quads". The routing table code in the kernel performs a very fast bit-wise AND comparison when checking if an address is in a given network space (network/netmask). The trick here is to store the dotted-quad IP addresses, network addresses and netmasks in your tables as UINT32, and then perform the same 32-bit bit-wise AND for your matching. eg

```
SET @test_addr = inet_aton('1.2.3.4');
SET @network_one = inet_aton('1.2.3.0');
SET @network_two = inet_aton('4.5.6.0');
SET @network_netmask = inet_aton('255.255.255.0');

SELECT (@test_addr & @network_netmask) = @network_one AS IS_MATCHED;
+------------+
| IS_MATCHED |
+------------+
|          1 |
+------------+

SELECT (@test_addr & @network_netmask) = @network_two AS IS_NOT_MATCHED;
+----------------+
| IS_NOT_MATCHED |
+----------------+
|              0 |
+----------------+
```

Comment: To get the `@network_netmask` value from `24` instead of `255.255.255.0`, you can use this: `((POWER(2,32)-1)<<(32-@mask)) & (POWER(2,32)-1);` where `@mask` is the 24 value. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/282528/10952503)

Answer (score 3):

For `IPv4`, you can use:

```
SET @length = 4;

SELECT  INET_NTOA(ipaddr), INET_NTOA(searchaddr), INET_NTOA(mask)
FROM  (
  SELECT
        (1 << (@length * 8)) - 1 & ~((1 << (@length * 8 - cidr)) - 1) AS mask,
        CAST(CONV(SUBSTR(HEX(ipaddr), 1, @length * 2), 16, 10) AS DECIMAL(20)) AS ipaddr,
        CAST(CONV(SUBSTR(HEX(@myaddr), 1, @length * 2), 16, 10) AS DECIMAL(20)) AS searchaddr
  FROM  ip
) ipo
WHERE ipaddr & mask = searchaddr & mask
```

Comment: Thank you. I was pretty sure I didn't need a table to do CIDRs, but could compute/create the masks on the fly like this. I believe the mask can be simplified to    ~((1 << cidr)-1), where ((1<<cidr)-1) sets the rightmost cidr bits true, and the NOT, IE: the ~ reverses all the bits in the unsigned long so that the rightmost cidr bits are false and all those to the left are true. The Win7+ calc, using the Programmer interface, is quite helpful in such matters.

Answer (score 1):

## Generating IP Address Ranges as Integers

> If your database doesn't support fancy bitwise operations, you can use a simplified integer based approach.

The following example is using PostgreSQL:

```
select (cast(split_part(split_part('4.0.0.0/8', '/', 1), '.', 1) as bigint) * (256 * 256 * 256) +
        cast(split_part(split_part('4.0.0.0/8', '/', 1), '.', 2) as bigint) * (256 * 256      ) +
        cast(split_part(split_part('4.0.0.0/8', '/', 1), '.', 3) as bigint) * (256            ) +
        cast(split_part(split_part('4.0.0.0/8', '/', 1), '.', 4) as bigint)) 
        as network,

       (cast(split_part(split_part('4.0.0.0/8', '/', 1), '.', 1) as bigint) * (256 * 256 * 256) +
        cast(split_part(split_part('4.0.0.0/8', '/', 1), '.', 2) as bigint) * (256 * 256      ) +
        cast(split_part(split_part('4.0.0.0/8', '/', 1), '.', 3) as bigint) * (256            ) +
        cast(split_part(split_part('4.0.0.0/8', '/', 1), '.', 4) as bigint)) + cast(
          pow(256, (32 - cast(split_part('4.0.0.0/8', '/', 2) as bigint)) / 8) - 1 as bigint
        ) as broadcast;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.  You could build a table of the cidr masks, join it, and then compare the ip anded (`&` in MySQL) with the mask with the ban block ipaddress.  Would that do what you want?

If you don't want to build a mask table, you could compute the mask as `-1 << (x-cidr)` with `x = 64` or `32` depending.

Answer (score 0):

```
#my subnet 
SET @subnet = '192.168.1.0';
SET @mask = '255.255.254.0';
SET @cidr = 23;


#check 192.168.0.4 is in my subnet

#use mask
SELECT INET_ATON('192.168.0.4') & INET_ATON(@mask) = INET_ATON(@subnet) & INET_ATON(@mask) AS in_subnet;

#use cidr
SELECT INET_ATON('192.168.0.4') & -1 << 32 - @cidr = INET_ATON(@subnet) & -1 << 32 - @cidr AS in_subnet;
```