# Comparison of IP address with CIDR in database mysql

Tags: java, mysql, network-programming

I have the task of comparing the IP address with the CIDR in the database (MYSQL) to get the value of the access technology.
for example, I got a client's 10.1.2.5.
And in the list of networks I have a list:

```
10.1.0.0/24 ETHERNET
10.1.1.0/24 WIFI
10.1.2.0/24 WIFI
```

I understand how to store this pair in the database. And then how can I compare the lines from the base with the value of the IP address.
pls help me

Comment: Is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_prefix_match what you are looking for? So given a IP address (doesn't matter if host or subnet) it will return the subnet-IP address from your lookup table.

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595748/is-there-way-to-match-ip-with-ipcidr-straight-from-select-query

Comment: @RiggsFolly It looks like this is what I was looking for. Several replies in one topic at once. I will study and test this theory, and give feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT name
FROM test
WHERE ip = INET_ATON(@address) & mask;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a75ea7c00b7447a98e1c0a0ec8d4336f