# PLSQL Function to convert IPV4 to IPV6

Tags: oracle, function, plsql, ipv6, ipv4

Looking for pl\sql (Oracle env.) conversion function which excepts  a string as an input (IPV4 format)  and returns IPV6 format , for example :

Send - **10.85.79.96**  will return **0:0:0:0:0:ffff:a55:4f60**

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I don't know what you plan to use it for, but please be aware that conversion like this only applies in very specific circumstances (IPv6 sockets accepting IPv4 connections) and that usually there is no visible relationship between IPv4 and IPv6 addresses. (just making sure everybody reading this question understands that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this set of functions:

```
FUNCTION UncompressIpV6(Ip IN VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 DETERMINISTIC IS
    IpFull VARCHAR2(40);
    len INTEGER := 7;
BEGIN
    IF REGEXP_LIKE(Ip, '::') THEN
        IpFull := REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(Ip, '^::', '0::'), '::$', '::0');
        IF REGEXP_LIKE(Ip, ':\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+$') THEN
            -- Mixed notation, e.g.: 0::FFFF:129.144.52.38
            len := 6;
        END IF;
        WHILE REGEXP_COUNT(IpFull, ':') <= len LOOP
            IpFull := REGEXP_REPLACE(IpFull, '::', ':0::');
        END LOOP;   
        RETURN REGEXP_REPLACE(IpFull, '::', ':');
    ELSE
        RETURN Ip;
    END IF;

END UncompressIpV6;



FUNCTION Ip2Decimal(IP IN VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER DETERMINISTIC IS
     DecimalIp NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN

    IF REGEXP_LIKE(IP, ':') THEN
        IF REGEXP_LIKE(IP, '\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+$') THEN
            -- Mixed notation, e.g.: 0:0:0:0:0:FFFF:129.144.52.38
            SELECT SUM(TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(UncompressIpV6(IP), '[[:xdigit:]]+', 1, LEVEL), 'XXXX') * POWER(65536, 8-LEVEL))
            INTO DecimalIp
            FROM dual 
            CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 6;

            SELECT DecimalIp + SUM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(REGEXP_SUBSTR(UncompressIpV6(IP), '\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+$'), '\d+', 1, LEVEL) * POWER(256, 4-LEVEL))
            INTO DecimalIp
            FROM dual 
            CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 4;
            RETURN DecimalIp;       
        ELSE
            SELECT SUM(TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(UncompressIpV6(IP), '[[:xdigit:]]+', 1, LEVEL), 'XXXX') * POWER(65536, 8-LEVEL))
            INTO DecimalIp
            FROM dual 
            CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 8;
            RETURN DecimalIp;
        END IF;
    ELSE
        SELECT SUM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(IP, '\d+', 1, LEVEL) * POWER(256, 4-LEVEL))
        INTO DecimalIp
        FROM dual 
        CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 4;
        RETURN DecimalIp;   
    END IF;

END Ip2Decimal;




FUNCTION Decimal2Ip(IpDecimal IN NUMBER) RETURN VARCHAR2 DETERMINISTIC IS

    IP VARCHAR2(16);
    Octet INTEGER;
    v_IpDecimal INTEGER := IpDecimal;

BEGIN
    IF IpDecimal IS NULL THEN 
        RETURN NULL; 
    END IF;
    IF IpDecimal > 2**32 - 1 THEN
        RAISE NUMERIC_OVERFLOW;
    END IF;

    FOR i IN 1..4 LOOP
        Octet := TRUNC(v_IpDecimal/256**(4-i));
        v_IpDecimal := v_IpDecimal - Octet * 256**(4-i);
        IP := IP ||'.'||Octet;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN SUBSTR(IP, 2);

END Decimal2Ip;



FUNCTION Decimal2IPv6(IpDecimal IN NUMBER) RETURN VARCHAR2 DETERMINISTIC IS

    IP VARCHAR2(40);
    Octet INTEGER;
    v_IpDecimal NUMBER := IpDecimal;

BEGIN
    IF IpDecimal IS NULL THEN 
        RETURN NULL; 
    END IF;
    IF IpDecimal > 2**128 - 1 THEN
        RAISE NUMERIC_OVERFLOW;
    END IF;

    FOR i IN 1..8 LOOP
        Octet := TRUNC(v_IpDecimal/65536**(8-i));
        v_IpDecimal := v_IpDecimal - Octet * 65536**(8-i);
        IP := IP ||':'||TO_CHAR(Octet, 'fmXXXX');
    END LOOP;
    RETURN LOWER(SUBSTR(IP, 2));

END Decimal2IPv6;
```

Example:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(Decimal2IPv6(Ip2Decimal('10.85.79.96')), ':0:', ':ffff:', 1, 3) 
FROM dual;

0:0:0:0:0:ffff:a55:4f60
```

Comment: Also have a look at this more advanced PL/SQL package:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43221720/oracle-pl-sql-how-to-calculate-range-ip-for-ipv6-cidr/43226773?noredirect=1#43226773 There the solution would be `SELECT IP_Util.RAW2IP(UTL_RAW.BIT_OR(IP_Util.IP2RAW('10.85.79.96', 6), IP_Util.IP2RAW('::ffff:0:0', 6)), 6) from dual;`