# Converting IPV6 to IPV4

Tags: oracle, plsql

Need your help here , one of our column table holds IP addresses in IPv6 format, we need to add additional column which will contain it's translation to IPv4 format, of course it will have to verify the addresses is with in the range of IPv4 else it will update the IPv4 column with 'N/A' .

For ex:

```
Ipv6                       Ipv4
-----                      ------
0:0:0:0:0:ffff:808:808     8.8.8.8
```

Thanks for the help !!!

Comment: Are you not happy with this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45075887/plsql-function-to-convert-ipv4-to-ipv6 It provides conversion in both directions.
You can use it like this: `Decimal2IP(Ip2Decimal('::'||REGEXP_SUBSTR('0:0:0:0:0:ffff:808:808', '[[:xdigit:]]{1,4}:[[:xdigit:]]{1,4}$')))`. Replace `RAISE NUMERIC_OVERFLOW;`  by `RETURN 'N/A';` if required.

Comment: Do you have to support also mixed notation like `0:0:0:0:0:FFFF:129.144.52.38`

Comment: Wow Thanks for the quick response , It did the work !!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PLSQL Function to convert IPV4 to IPV6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45075887/plsql-function-to-convert-ipv4-to-ipv6)