# how to query hex/raw data in a range for ipv6

Tags: oracle, ipv6

I want to be able to store ipv6 addresses and then be able to query them to find a range etc. If you see the following example of an ipv4 of what i am doing i would like to perform the same for ipv6.

```
CREATE TABLE DATA 
(
  ID NUMBER(10, 0) NOT NULL 
, SRC VARCHAR2(18 BYTE) NOT NULL 
, SRC_NET VARCHAR2(18 BYTE) 
, DST VARCHAR2(18 BYTE) NOT NULL 
, DST_NET VARCHAR2(18 BYTE) 
, PROTOCOL VARCHAR2(4 BYTE) 
, PORTS VARCHAR2(64 BYTE) 
, TS_CREATED TIMESTAMP(6) DEFAULT SYSTIMESTAMP NOT NULL 
, SRC_SOCT1 NUMBER(3, 0) 
, SRC_SOCT2 NUMBER(3, 0) 
, SRC_SOCT3 NUMBER(3, 0) 
, SRC_SOCT4 NUMBER(3, 0) 
, SRC_EOCT1 NUMBER(3, 0) 
, SRC_EOCT2 NUMBER(3, 0) 
, SRC_EOCT3 NUMBER(3, 0) 
, SRC_EOCT4 NUMBER(3, 0) 
, SRC_CIDR NUMBER(2, 0) 
, SRC_NET_SOCT1 NUMBER(3, 0) 
, SRC_NET_SOCT2 NUMBER(3, 0) 
, SRC_NET_SOCT3 NUMBER(3, 0) 
, SRC_NET_SOCT4 NUMBER(3, 0) 
, SRC_NET_EOCT1 NUMBER(3, 0) 
, SRC_NET_EOCT2 NUMBER(3, 0) 
, SRC_NET_EOCT3 NUMBER(3, 0) 
, SRC_NET_EOCT4 NUMBER(3, 0) 
, SRC_NET_CIDR NUMBER(2, 0) 
, DST_SOCT1 NUMBER(3, 0) 
, DST_SOCT2 NUMBER(3, 0) 
, DST_SOCT3 NUMBER(3, 0) 
, DST_SOCT4 NUMBER(3, 0) 
, DST_EOCT1 NUMBER(3, 0) 
, DST_EOCT2 NUMBER(3, 0) 
, DST_EOCT3 NUMBER(3, 0) 
, DST_EOCT4 NUMBER(3, 0) 
, DST_CIDR NUMBER(2, 0) 
, DST_NET_SOCT1 NUMBER(3, 0) 
, DST_NET_SOCT2 NUMBER(3, 0) 
, DST_NET_SOCT3 NUMBER(3, 0) 
, DST_NET_SOCT4 NUMBER(3, 0) 
, DST_NET_EOCT1 NUMBER(3, 0) 
, DST_NET_EOCT2 NUMBER(3, 0) 
, DST_NET_EOCT3 NUMBER(3, 0) 
, DST_NET_EOCT4 NUMBER(3, 0) 
, DST_NET_CIDR NUMBER(2, 0) 
, TS_UPDATED TIMESTAMP(6) DEFAULT SYSTIMESTAMP NOT NULL 
) 

Insert into EXPORT_TABLE (ID,SRC,SRC_NET,DST,DST_NET,PROTOCOL,PORTS,TS_CREATED,SRC_SOCT1,SRC_SOCT2,SRC_SOCT3,SRC_SOCT4,SRC_EOCT1,SRC_EOCT2,SRC_EOCT3,SRC_EOCT4,SRC_CIDR,SRC_NET_SOCT1,SRC_NET_SOCT2,SRC_NET_SOCT3,SRC_NET_SOCT4,SRC_NET_EOCT1,SRC_NET_EOCT2,SRC_NET_EOCT3,SRC_NET_EOCT4,SRC_NET_CIDR,DST_SOCT1,DST_SOCT2,DST_SOCT3,DST_SOCT4,DST_EOCT1,DST_EOCT2,DST_EOCT3,DST_EOCT4,DST_CIDR,DST_NET_SOCT1,DST_NET_SOCT2,DST_NET_SOCT3,DST_NET_SOCT4,DST_NET_EOCT1,DST_NET_EOCT2,DST_NET_EOCT3,DST_NET_EOCT4,DST_NET_CIDR,TS_UPDATED) values (916,'10.105.138.244','10.105.138.0/24','10.108.235.128/25','10.108.235.128/25','TCP','4739',to_timestamp('03-SEP-19 12.34.25.806754000','DD-MON-RR HH24.MI.SSXFF'),10,105,138,244,10,105,138,244,32,10,105,138,0,10,105,138,255,24,10,108,235,128,10,108,235,255,25,10,108,235,128,10,108,235,255,25,to_timestamp('03-SEP-19 12.34.25.806754000','DD-MON-RR HH24.MI.SSXFF'));
Insert into EXPORT_TABLE (ID,SRC,SRC_NET,DST,DST_NET,PROTOCOL,PORTS,TS_CREATED,SRC_SOCT1,SRC_SOCT2,SRC_SOCT3,SRC_SOCT4,SRC_EOCT1,SRC_EOCT2,SRC_EOCT3,SRC_EOCT4,SRC_CIDR,SRC_NET_SOCT1,SRC_NET_SOCT2,SRC_NET_SOCT3,SRC_NET_SOCT4,SRC_NET_EOCT1,SRC_NET_EOCT2,SRC_NET_EOCT3,SRC_NET_EOCT4,SRC_NET_CIDR,DST_SOCT1,DST_SOCT2,DST_SOCT3,DST_SOCT4,DST_EOCT1,DST_EOCT2,DST_EOCT3,DST_EOCT4,DST_CIDR,DST_NET_SOCT1,DST_NET_SOCT2,DST_NET_SOCT3,DST_NET_SOCT4,DST_NET_EOCT1,DST_NET_EOCT2,DST_NET_EOCT3,DST_NET_EOCT4,DST_NET_CIDR,TS_UPDATED) values (917,'10.105.138.242','10.105.138.0/24','10.108.235.128/25','10.108.235.128/25','TCP','4739',to_timestamp('03-SEP-19 12.34.25.817512000','DD-MON-RR HH24.MI.SSXFF'),10,105,138,242,10,105,138,242,32,10,105,138,0,10,105,138,255,24,10,108,235,128,10,108,235,255,25,10,108,235,128,10,108,235,255,25,to_timestamp('03-SEP-19 12.34.25.817512000','DD-MON-RR HH24.MI.SSXFF'));
```

with the above data i can find out if an address is within a certain network (range) using query

```
select * from data where 
src_soct1 >= 10 and src_eoct2 <= 10 
and src_soct1 >= 10 and src_eoct1 <= 10 
and src_soct2 >= 10 and src_eoct2 <= 10 
and src_soct3 >= 10 and src_eoct3 <= 10 
and src_soct4 >= 10 and src_eoct4 <= 10
```

I have read it is best to store ipv6 as `raw` in oracle. How can i achieve the same for ipv6 by storing them as `raw` or `hex` data OR is the only way to store them as decimals the same way?

There will be millions increasing to billions of rows.

Comment: Your IPv4 has a fundamental flaw. The octets have nothing to do with an IPv4 address, they are simply to make it easier for humans to read. IPv4 addresses are 32-bit unsigned integers, and they should be stored and manipulated as such, and you only convert to dotted-decimal notation when a human needs to see them. IPv6 is the same way, except the addresses are 128-bit unsigned integers. [This two-part answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53994/8499) explains all about IPv4 address manipulation.

Comment: This package should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43221720/oracle-pl-sql-how-to-calculate-range-ip-for-ipv6-cidr/43226773?noredirect=1#43226773 I would suggest to store IPv6 as `RAW` value, then you can run queries for example with `UTL_RAW.BIT_AND`