# Find Subnet Address given IP Address and Prefix Length in Oracle 12c/ PL SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Given IP Address (example: 12.12.12.12/24) return prefix IP address (example: 12.12.12.0).
How can we make these conversions in SQL?

I was trying to string together a method by converting IP address to binary and then ANDing them. There are a tonne of examples in general, nothing that works for PL/SQL. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: See this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43221720/oracle-pl-sql-how-to-calculate-range-ip-for-ipv6-cidr/43226773#43226773

Comment: I am looking to extract Prefix IP given CIDR notation, not decimal notation.

Comment: Yes, it's all available in the package I provided in the link

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way using REGEXP_REPLACE().  The regular expression describes the string, with the 'remembered' part in parentheses.  The remembered part is everything up to and including the last period in the string.  We don;t want the rest of the string.   The replace part of the call replaces with the first remembered part (denoted as \1) followed by the 0.

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('12.12.12.12/24', '(.*\.).*', '\10') new_ip
from dual;


NEW_IP    
----------
12.12.12.0
1 row selected.
```

Comment: This would *only* work for a prefix length of 24. I think the OP is looking for a more general method