# how to separate IP '103.151.184.6' and store as separate value in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

how to separate  IP '103.151.184.6' and store as separate value in SQL

Comment: What do you mean by "seperate"? Please show an example of how you want it seperated. Do you mean seperate by dots? What's the purpose of this?

Comment: Please show what did you try so far and what was wrong with it.

Comment: No idea why you like to do this, but you may have a look at this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43221720/oracle-pl-sql-how-to-calculate-range-ip-for-ipv6-cidr/43226773#43226773

Comment: Or do you maybe have a long text message *containing* that IP address and you want to copy that full address into one separate column? A regex may help you find it

Answer (score 0):

You should use [regexp_substr](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/functions116.htm). Then your code will be look like this.

```
select 
    regexp_substr('103.151.184.6','[^.]+', 1, level) 
from 
    dual
connect by 
    regexp_substr('103.151.184.6', '[^.]+', 1, level) is not null;
```

And the output will be this.

```
103
151
184
6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just get the 1<sup>st</sup> - 4<sup>th</sup> occurrences of numbers from the string:

```sql
SELECT value,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(value, '\d+', 1, 1) AS ip_value1,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(value, '\d+', 1, 2) AS ip_value2,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(value, '\d+', 1, 3) AS ip_value3,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(value, '\d+', 1, 4) AS ip_value4
FROM   table_name
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( value ) AS
SELECT '103.151.184.6' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | VALUE | IP_VALUE1 | IP_VALUE2 | IP_VALUE3 | IP_VALUE4 |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 103.151.184.6 | 103 | 151 | 184 | 6 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d99e739e2bdfe1d6b0182e08bcdbd35e)*